# iPhone not i.d.'ing callers after resetting all settings

Tags: iphone, caller-id

I used **Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings** on my iPhone, and now incoming phone calls are displayed as the telephone number, rather than the name from my Contacts.

I do notice that the telephone numbers in my Contacts app are (now?) *simply a string of 10 digits, rather than being formatted*.  I'm pretty sure it was formatted at one point.

Thought it might have something to do with **International Assist**, but turning that on or off doesn't change this.

I don't recall having to set anything initially to enable caller i.d., so I don't know what setting might have been reset.

Suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem turned out to be reactivating my (Verizon) phone.  Details here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3766509